# Android TabLayout always shows first tab indicator irrespective of which tab is selected

Tags: android, tabs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rLjd.png)[Here, my first tab selection indicator is always visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2GQr.png)
I have added TabLayout inside a fragment. But indicator of first tab is always visible even though I have selected other tabs. Please find the screen shot.

It will be of great help if anybody can suggest on what mistake I am making.

Please find the below code:

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
 Fragment frag1 = new MyFragment1();
 adapter.addFragment(frag1, getString(R.string.frag_video));

 FragmentMediaPhotos frag2 = new MyFragment2();
 adapter.addFragment(frag2, getString(R.string.frag_photo));

 FragmentMediaMusic frag3 = new MyFragment3();
 adapter.addFragment(frag3, getString(R.string.frag_audios));
 mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

 After this setting three layout like this:

 TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_tab_text_view, null);
 tabOne.setText("Video");
 mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
```

Comment: post your code so we can check it

Comment: have u set your viewpager with tablayout? //  tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

Comment: As a workaround, maybe use tab.select()?

Comment: @Nidhi: yes setting viewpager with table layout.

Comment: I have posted the code. Please have a look at my code

Comment: @DDerTyp: tab.select() can't be used as my query is forever selected first tab which shouldn't be shown with selected indicator when other tabs are selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My activity was extended from BaseActivity and I kept BaseActivity as abstract. 
Keeping BaseActivity abstract caused the issue.